# Corrupt frames: what to do

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, software-recommendation, recommendation, mxf

I’ve discovered some corrupt frames in the footage I am working on (.mxf format, shot on Sony PXW 70, I only have access to the files copied to the hard drive, and the broken frames are in the unedited files).
I’ve checked the file with ffmpeg -v error -i (“[h264 @ 0x7fedd70abe00] error while decoding MB 15 37, bytestream -5”) and tried to repair it with ffmpeg -y -i. Not an experienced user though, so unsurprisingly that didn’t work, same broken frame in the same place in the output file.

Here’s the frame itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwVkj.jpg

So, I guess my questions are: What might be the cause of that? Is there a way to fix it/avoid it in the future?

Would be super thankful for any advice (googling hints included).

Comment: Compression error, possibly due to camera overheating or some defect/bug in the camera. Transcode it once with `ffmpeg -threads:v 1 -enable_er true -i ...` and check.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks a lot.
Tried it, 

`toharsky$ /Volumes/FFmpeg\ 4.1.1/ffmpeg -threads:v 1 -enable_er true -i /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/toharsky/Downloads/Clip0048.MXF output.MXF`

but seem to be getting another mistake now:
`Unrecognized option 'i /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/toharsky/Downloads/Clip0048.MXF'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

What am I doing wrong? the problem is not the path, it's recognised when I do `/Volumes/FFmpeg\ 4.1.1/ffmpeg -v error -i /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/toharsky/Downloads/Clip0048.MXF -f null - &> corruptions.log`

Comment: Add -report and run. Share report.

Comment: @Gyan, thanks again. I was able to run it now, no clue what was the problem.
Here's the [log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=146Ztk2-C42sSRzocPrrHAWc--DKIlyy8). The corrupt frame is still there after transcoding.